# Why can't I open xls file in browser using TransmitFile?

Tags: c#

I open `.XLS/.DOC/.PDF` files with `Response.TransmitFile()`. The `PDF`  get opened, but the `XLS`-and the `DOC` files not Open.

```
string path = @"D:\\Files\\" + Request.QueryString.Get("PSFname");

int startIndex = Request.QueryString.Get("PSFname").IndexOf(".");
string type = Request.QueryString.Get("PSFname").Substring(startIndex + 1);

if (type == "doc" || type == "docx")
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
}
else if (type == "xls" || type == "xlsx")
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Request.QueryString.Get("PSFname"));

}
else if (type == "pdf" || type == "PDF")
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
}
Response.TransmitFile(path);
```

Comment: You get any error or exception? How do you open your file?

Comment: no xls file download but not open on browser

Comment: did you mean you can download file but van not open file in browser?

Comment: @ManishParakhiya exactly

Comment: @HiralNayak Do you have browser plugins for XLS and DOC files? Otherwise, the browser will not know how to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can open PDF file in browser because you have Add-On for pdf file added in your browser that opens pdf file for you in browser.

But there is no any Add-On for the same for Word and Excel file. so these file is not opens in browser.

Comment: now what is the solution to open Excel file in browser

Comment: You have to find equivalent plugin for that. but this only work for in browser that have that plugin.

Comment: @when i use Internet Explorer then open popup for asking to save file or open but not work for google chrome